# Center manifold reduction

Tags: dynamical-systems

This a verbatim copy of an [example](http://exordio.qfb.umich.mx/archivos%20pdf%20de%20trabajo%20umsnh/aphilosofia/2007/libro%20de%20sistemas%20dinamicos/Lecture3.pdf) on center manifold reduction on nonlinear dynamical system I found on some lecture note:

Consider the system
\begin{align*}
\dot{x}&=x^2y-x^5\\
\dot{y}&=-y+x^2
\end{align*}
Again $(0,0)$ is an equilibrium point and the system is in canonical form
$$J_X(0,0)=\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\0&-1\end{bmatrix}.$$ Consider $y=h(x)=ax^2+bx^3+O(x^4)$. Then as in previous example
$$\dot{y}=h'(x)\dot{x}=2a^2x^5+[2a(b-1)+3ab]x^6+O(x^7)$$
and
$$\dot{y}=-h(x)+x^2=-(a-1)x^2-bx^3+O(x^4).$$
We deduce that $a=1$ and $b=0$. The center manifold is given by
$$y=h(x)=x^2+O(x^4)$$ and the dynamics are governed by
$$\dot{x}=x^4+O(x^5).$$

My question is how do we obtain the last equation? I was guessing that we substitute $y=x^2+O(x^4)$ into $\dot{x}=x^2y-x^5$. But if we do so we should have
$$\dot{x}=x^2(x^2+O(x^4))-x^5=x^4+O(x^6)-x^5.$$ I am completely lost at the moment.

Comment: $O(x^6)-x^5=O(x^5)$ (and even $\Theta(x^5)$). See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation

Comment: What is the general for rule $O(x^m)-x^n$?

Comment: In general, if $g=O(f)$ then $f+O(g)=O(f)$. *This is a direct consequence of the definition of the Big-O relation*. Use this for $f(x)=x^5$ and $g(x)=x^6$. Even better, read and ponder the page I linked to.